# Openpyxl: TypeError - Concatenation of several columns into one cell per row

Tags: python, excel, concatenation, openpyxl

I am new to openpyxl and cannot figure out what the reason for my error is. I hope you can see the problem and show me what to change!

**What I want to do:**
I want to concatenate the cells from columns F to M per row and put the concatenated value into column E like below. 
(The rows do not always fill up from column F to column M, since per row are different kind of signals. But I have not put an if clause for this yet. This is just an information about the structure.)

Input:

```
A B C D E F   G   H  .. M
.......   E1  90  2A .. 26
.......   0   80  F8 ..
```

Output:

```
A B C D E         F   G   H  .. M
....... E1902A..26
....... 080F8..
```

**What I did so far (Code):**

```
theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('T013.xlsx')
allSheetNames = theFile.sheetnames 
print("All sheet names {} " .format(theFile.sheetnames)) 
sheet = theFile.active

#loop to concatenate
for i,row in enumerate(sheet.rows,1):
        for column in range(6,13): #column F-M
            sRow=str(i)  
            Ecell = sheet['E' + sRow]
            ref = sheet["F:M"] #range of cells 
            for cell in range(ref):
                values = str(cell.value)  #collect data
            Ecell.value = ''.join(values) # write values
```

**Which kind of error I get (complete Traceback):**

```
C:\Users\..\Desktop\Practical Part\CAN Python>python ConcatenateHEX.py
All sheet names ['T013']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ConcatenateBIN.py", line 38, in <module>
    for cell in range(ref):
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I already tried to change the 'ref' variable but the error is always the same!
Could you please support me? Thank you very much!

EDIT (2/10/2020):
Further, I want to use the function for all rows which are too many to write down. Therefore I came up with this change:

```
def concat_f_to_m():
for row_value in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    values=[]
    del values[:]   
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=6, max_col=14, min_row=row_value, max_row=row_value):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value != None:
                values.append(str(cell.value))
            else:
                del values[:] 
                break
                #print(values)
    sheet[f'E{row_value}'].value= ''.join(values)
```

concat_f_to_m()

I cannot overcome the issue that all the values from row 1 to row xyz are printed in the row_value cell (e.g. row_value=13, all values from row 1 to 13 are concatenated in cell E13). I therefore wanted to iterate over row_value in order to go through all rows but somehow that does not work. Could you give me a hint how to concatenate through all rows by joining the values list at the certain row? Thank you!

Comment: It's the same error as in your last question: `ref` is of type `tuple` and `range(...` expectes type `int`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `openpyxl`, I created a little function that will do what you want for a line at a time:

```py
import openpyxl

theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook('T013.xlsx')
allSheetNames = theFile.sheetnames 
print("All sheet names: {}" .format(theFile.sheetnames)) 
sheet = theFile.active


def concat_f_to_m(row_value):
    values=[]
    del values[:]
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=6, max_col=13, min_row=row_value, max_row=row_value):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value == None:
                pass
            else:
                values.append(str(cell.value))
    sheet[f'E{row_value}'].value= ''.join(values)


concat_f_to_m(1)
concat_f_to_m(2)
theFile.save('T013.xlsx')
```

**Output:**

[image: Excel Output]

Comment: Thank you a lot for showing me how you did it. it worked for me as well. Can I ask you something? I do not understand why you first create a values list and then remove all items in the list (del values[:]), even though there are no items to begin with?

Comment: This is to ensure the list is empty when you begin iterating through the rows.

Comment: thanks for the explanation! I am right now working on getting all the rows concatenated at column E in their row. Unfortunately, I cannot get the concatenated values list in the E cell. I have posted the code in my first post (see section EDIT 02/10/2020). Could you have a look at it? Thank you very much for your support :-)

Comment: Please make a new post with the edit you provided above, and I'd be glad to help

Comment: I did! Here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143273/openpyxl-concatenation-of-several-columns-into-one-cell-per-row-multi-row)