# Openpyxl: Concatenation of several columns into one cell per row (Multi-row)

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

This question is a follow up to: [Openpyxl: TypeError - Concatenation of several columns into one cell per row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087517/openpyxl-typeerror-concatenation-of-several-columns-into-one-cell-per-row/60102425?noredirect=1#comment106373320_60102425)

**What I want to do:**
I want to concatenate the cells from columns F to M per row and put the concatenated value into column E like below. This needs to be done for all rows at the same time.

Input:

```
A B C D E F   G   H  .. M
.......   E1  90  2A .. 26
.......   0   80  F8 ..
```

Output:

```
A B C D E         F   G   H  .. M
....... E1902A..26
....... 080F8..
```

**Code:**

```
def concat_f_to_m():
    for row_value in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
        values=[]
        del values[:]
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=6, max_col=14, min_row=row_value, max_row=row_value):
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value != None:
                    values.append(str(cell.value))

                else:
                    del values[:]
                    pass

            sheet[f'E{row_value}'].value= ''.join(values)

concat_f_to_m()
```

Also I have set the max column to column N (14) as the longest code goes until column M and I want to stop the loop once there is no entry found in order to go out and join the list's items. I cannot overcome the issue that despite a print of the values list shows only the row's items, it does not write it down into the cell.
Could you give me a hint how to concatenate through all rows by joining the values list at the certain row? Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over Worksheets, Rows, Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42974450/iterate-over-worksheets-rows-columns)

Comment: @stovfl Thank you a lot! It did not help but I will post the correct implementation above! I was on the wrong track the whole time (I thought if I put the `join(values)` line after `append` it is not going to join the whole list as it is going to iterate over it. Somehow that's wrong. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Correct implementation:

```
def concat_f_to_m():
for row_value in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
    values=[]
    del values[:]
    for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=6, max_col=14, min_row=row_value, max_row=row_value):
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value != None:

                values.append(str(cell.value))
                sheet[f'E{row_value}'].value= ''.join(values)
            else:
                del values[:] 
                break

concat_f_to_m()
```