# Correcting HEX values in Excel by appending additional zero

Tags: excel, hex, openpyxl

I did find a solution to previous asked problem on multi-row concatenation (`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60143273/openpyxl-concatenation-of-several-columns-into-one-cell-per-row-multi-row`), but I found out that the HEX code is not displayed correctly in Excel. I found out that there are two cases, that I need to correct (Import of .csv/.txt after formatting columns/sheet did not work) the values that have a single digit in the columns F to M before concatenating them. 
Excel changes `"00"` to `"0"` as well as `"02"` (or any other number instead of 2) to `"2"`. This is important to me as the bits are going to be lost and all the data is going to be useless.

Desired Input:

```
A  B  C D  E            F            G   H  .. M
.. 2E .... 0000000000000AA4.. 
...4A ...  0002478304..
```

Current Input:

```
A  B  C D  E            F            G   H  .. M
.. 2E .... 0000000AA4.. 
...4A ...  0247834..
```

Organized:

```
A  B  C D  E            F            G   H  .. M
.. 2E .... 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A A4.. 
...4A ...  00  02 47 83 04..
```

Code that I worked on up until now:

```
def concat_f_to_m():
    for row_value in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
        values=[]
        del values[:]
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=6, max_col=14, min_row=row_value, max_row=row_value):
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value != None:
                    if cell.value == '0':
                        values.append("00")
                        print("zeros", values)
                    else:   
                        values.append(str(cell.value))
                        print("non-zeros", values)
                    sheet[f'E{row_value}'].value= ''.join(values)
                else:
                    del values[:] 
                    break
```

I only worked on the one zero instead of two zero's issue before going over to solve the digit issue. Somehow the program does not even go into the `if cell.value == '0'` part. I do not know what the issue is. Could you explain to me why I am on the wrong track? Thank you!

Comment: you need to format the cells as text for excel to stop removing leading zeros (e.g. when you import from csv, you have to do this per column). `if cell.value == '0'` doesn't evaluate because the value is 0 (Int) and not '0' (string)

Comment: If I were doing this in Excel, I would use `Power Query` to import the csv as **text**, then join the columns, and then write it to the worksheet.  Can you not do something similar with openpyxl?

Comment: try `if str(cell.value) == '0':`, this will give you a string representation of the integer value, which you can then modify to append the leading zero, or do as you have and replace it with a string `00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `.zfill(x)` to your string values so it is **AT LEAST** `x` length. Since you want 2 characters, you'll `.zfill(2)`.

```py
def concat_f_to_m():
    for row_value in range(1, sheet.max_row+1):
        values=[]
        del values[:]
        for row in sheet.iter_rows(min_col=6, max_col=14, min_row=row_value, max_row=row_value):
            for cell in row:
                if cell.value != None:
                    values.append(str(cell.value).zfill(2))
                    sheet[f'E{row_value}'].value= ''.join(values)
                else:
                    del values[:] 
                    break
```